# MyBatis association dependency on order by

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am trying to fetch data using MyBatis association. The data fetched includes list of person, each of these person have a list of companies associated with them. (see POJO) Currently, there are only two person in DB, say P1 and P0. P1 is associated with Company C1 and C2 and P0 is associated with only C1. (see sql result)

My result map contains a map for person, which itself contains an association of a map for company. (see result map)

When I am fetching the data in sql three rows are coming in the following order: (see sql result)

1. P1 with C1
2. P0 with C1
3. P1 with C2

When I am using "order by person, company" I am getting a correct object, i.e., List of person having two value one for P1 and other for P0, with P1 having list of C1 and C2, and P0 having list of only C1. (see JSON#1)

However, when I am not using "order by" then I am getting incorrect object list having a two objects of P1 (having list of C1 and C2). There is no object of P0. (see JSON#2)

I tried using id (as unique identifier) for company and person result map. I tried nested mapping as well.

Java side:

POJO:

```java
public class Person {
    private String personId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<CompanyWiseDetails> companyWiseDetails;

    // setters and getters
}

public class CompanyWiseDetails {
    private String companyId;
    private String companyName;
    private String payrollCycle;
    private Double januaryCatch;


    // setters and getters
}

DAO:

final Map<Object, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
paramMap.put("universeEndDate", this.getUniverseEndDate());
paramMap.put("projectionDate", projectionDate);
SqlSession.selectList("fetchData")
```

Result Map:

```xml
<resultMap id="person" type="Person">
    <id property="personId" column="person_id" />
    <result property="firstName" column="first_name" />
    <result property="lastName" column="last_name" />
    <!-- few other fields which can be null -->
    <collection
            property="companyWiseDetailsList"
            resultMap="companyEntityWiseDetails" />
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="companyEntityWiseDetails"
            type="CompanyWiseDetails">
    <id property="companyId" column="company_id" />
    <result property="companyName" column="company_name" />
    <result property="payrollCycle" column="payroll_cycle" />
    <!-- few other fields which can be null -->
</resultMap>
```

SQL:

```sql
<select id="fetchData" resultMap="person" >
    <include refid="toCreateTemporary_table"/>
    select
        table_one.person_id as person_id,
        company_table.hr_company_code as company_id,
        tCompany.PayrollCycle as payroll_cycle
    from table_one table_one
        join company_table_strategy company_table
            on company_table.person_id =  table_one.person_id
            and company_table.as_on_date = #{projectionDate}
            and company_table.tt_end= #{universeEndDate}
        join tCompany
            on company_table.hr_company_code = tCompany.HRCompanyCode
        left join
            #temporary_table
            on #temporary_table.company_id = company_table.hr_company_code
            and #temporary_table.person_id = table_one.person_id
    where
        table_one.as_on_date = #{projectionDate}
        and table_one.tt_end= #{universeEndDate}
    order by
        person_id, entity_id
    drop table #temporary_table
     </select>
```

SQL output

```csv
person_id    company_id    payroll_cycle    company_name    cash_compensation    random_percentage    income             comp           field1             bonus             field2
P1           C1            bi_weekly        C1_name         5000.00000000        50.00000000          200112.10000000    60.10000000    NULL               NULL              NULL
P0           C1            bi_weekly        C1_name         5000.00000000        50.00000000          100112.10000000    30.10000000    NULL               NULL              NULL
P1           C2            bi_weekly        C2_name         5000.00000000        50.00000000          200112.10000000    30.10000000    362906.82000000    25000.00000000    1000.00000000
```

Response JSON when order by is used:

```json
[
    {
        "personId": "P0",
        "firstName": null,
        "lastName": null,
        "companyEntityWiseDetailsList": [
            {
                "companyId": "C1",
                "companyName": null,
                "payrollCycle": "bi_weekly"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "personId": "P1",
        "firstName": null,
        "lastName": null,
        "companyEntityWiseDetailsList": [
            {
                "companyId": "C1",
                "companyName": null,
                "payrollCycle": "bi_weekly",
            },
            {
                "companyId": "C2",
                "companyName": null,
                "payrollCycle": "bi_weekly",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Response JSON when order by is not used:

```json
[
    {
        "personId": "P1",
        "firstName": null,
        "lastName": null,
        "companyEntityWiseDetailsList": [
            {
                "companyId": "C1",
                "companyName": null,
                "payrollCycle": "bi_weekly",
            },
            {
                "companyId": "C2",
                "companyName": null,
                "payrollCycle": "bi_weekly",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "personId": "P1",
        "firstName": null,
        "lastName": null,
        "companyEntityWiseDetailsList": [
            {
                "companyId": "C1",
                "companyName": null,
                "payrollCycle": "bi_weekly",
            },
            {
                "companyId": "C2",
                "companyName": null,
                "payrollCycle": "bi_weekly",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Should "order by" have an impact on the result

Comment: There are obvious inconsistencies in the snippets (e.g. columns in SQL output don't match elements in the result maps, etc.). I may be able to help if you provide an executable repro like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues). As the issue is in result mapping part, you can use UNION ALL like [this](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/blob/master/so-55515218/src/test/resources/test/Mapper.xml#L72-L82) if it's easier.